# How can I use hook_bootstrap_colorize_text?

Tags: theming

I am using [Bootstrap](http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) subtheme called "pasporty_bootstrap". I would like to redefine function `bootstrap_colorize_text()` using hook, which can be found at:

http://drupalcode.org/project/bootstrap.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/theme/common.inc#l579

When I added following in my template.php file, nothing happened:

```
function pasporty_bootstrap_bootstrap_colorize_text(&$texts) {
  $texts = array(
    'contains' => array(
      t('Save') => 'primary'
    )
  );
  dpm($texts);
}
```

I tried to clear the cache multiple times but I wasn't successful. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: If you look at the code you've linked to: `(theme_get_setting('bootstrap_button_iconize')`...it's a **theme setting**, not a function (and subsequently, not a hook). It doesn't have the capacity to be overridden in the way you're trying to

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to point out other line - exactly `drupal_alter('bootstrap_colorize_text', $texts);` The comment above it clearly says it should enable sub-themes to override an array used for coloring.

Comment: Oops. missed that, sorry. Fortunately that's an easy one to debug :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
drupal_alter('bootstrap_colorize_text', $texts);
```

Will invoke a hook by the name of `bootstrap_colorize_text_alter()`...so you just need to update your code to:

```
function pasporty_bootstrap_bootstrap_colorize_text_alter(&$texts) {
  $texts = array(
    'contains' => array(
      t('Save') => 'primary'
    )
  );
  dpm($texts);
}
```

And clear the cache.